# How to keep seedlings fresh?

Tags: seedlings

I have ficus seedlings given to me in Chinese containers that are moist with wet paper towels. They have been in these containers for three days now and I can't get to pot them till Monday. Should I put them in the fridge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep them moist and at room temperature and they should be fine.  Do not put them in the windowsill or they could get too hot in the bag.